# Backbone with CakePHP JSON response

Tags: json, cakephp, backbone.js

I want JSON response from cakePHP which i will render using backbone.js. But instead of JSON response i am getting default.ctp content also along with JSON response i dont't know why. Is there something which i can do not to include default.ctp content in JSON response?

here is my code to fetch JSON

```
<?php
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);

//header('Content-type: text/json');
header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
//header("X-JSON: ".$content_for_layout);

$response['status'] = $status;
//$response['data']['titleForLayout'] = $title_for_layout;

$response['data']['validationErrors'] = $this->validationErrors;

$response['data']['sessionFlash'] = $this->Session->read('Message.flash.message');

//$response['data']['data'] = $this->data;
$response['data'][$this->request->params['controller']]['output'] = isset($output)?$output:null;

$output = json_encode($response);

if (isset($this->params['url']['callback'])) {
    echo $this->params['url']['callback'] . '(' . $output . ');';
} else {
    echo $output;
}
```

?>

where data->output contains the rows fetched.

Please help me out.

I get JSON response but the problem is  get default.ctp content surrounding the response which i don't want. is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you want Request Handling
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the layout to be ajax or an empty layout.

In the controller set this:

```
$this->layout = 'ajax';
```